# Webpage with mouse scroll control

Tags: angularjs, fullscreen, html

I wanto have a full screen website with mouse scroll control. For example, from page 1 to page 2, the navigation bar on the top is stays the same. however, if you do a mouse scroll down, content 1 changes to content 2.

1. Is there any code example for this?
2. More specifically, is there any Angularjs (with bootstrap) example for this?

[image]

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: not sure if scrollspy solves my problem. I want to flip the whole 'content area' from content 1 to content 2 (like go to a new page) with a mouse scroll down